# Dell inspiron 15R - weird behavior. It changes of applications by itself

Tags: dell-inspiron

Sometimes when I am using an application on my laptop Dell inspiron 15R - it has a weird behavior it means,it changes of applications by itself. 
For instance I am using the spotify application software as well but my laptop rises the images folder (it was already opened) however I have not selected to rise that application at all.
It happens when I have opened any application from start menu and I am working on a second application software, webpage or laptop's folder. 
I have Windows 8.1.
Could you please help me?

Comment: "rises the images folder" - What?

Answer (score 0):

there are several possible reasons for this:

1) could you possibly be touching the trackpad with your wrists?  Try using the laptop with an external mouse and see if the problem continues.  You can also try disabling tap to click on your touchpad driver - This will probably be found through control panel > Mouse settings.

2) AV, Malware, Spyware Scan your machine with a few different scanners.  try installing, running and uninstalling a few AV and spyware scanners.  There are loads of freebies out there.  The behaviour you described could easily be attributed to a piece of software "screwing with you" (so to speak).

3) Update your touchpad & chipset drivers.  You could possibly have out of date drivers which are misbehaving

4) System restore.  If this is new behavious, perhaps you installed some new software or windows updates which are causing this behaviour.  If that is the case, a system restore will fix that for you.

Hopefully one of these will point you in the right direction.